# hazelcast doesn't read from backup data

Tags: backup, hazelcast

I use hazelcast 3.8.4 and IMap.
I set in hazelcast.xml

```
<map name="default">
     <backup-count>1</backup-count>
     <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
     <read-backup-data>true</read-backup-data>
```

and I observe get/s per server in management center.

I think about this situation.
I put key 3, 4. And key 3 owner is server A, key 4 owner is server B.
before I set read-backup-data true, if I get key 3, only server A's get/s is up in management center.
After I set read-backup-data true, I expect not only get/s of server A but also server B will up.
But it didn't.
Why?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

read-backup-data would only kick in if you try to read the value from server B itself. It does not help to have multiple servers as value sources when using clients. This would mitigate the idea of how Hazelcast distributes not only data but also optimizes request latencies by sending requests from clients directly to the record-owing cluster node, if that makes sense.